# Rounding a distribution to minimize loss

Tags: probability, statistics, optimization

This question deals with the problem of choosing cutoff points such that rounding a random variable down to the nearest cutoff point doesn't lose "too much" of its mean. Formally:

Let $y$ be a continuous random variable over $\mathbb R^+$ with mean 1, and let $a$ be the infimum of its support.  Define an *$N$-rounding* of $y$ given a set of $N+1$ points  $a=x_1\leq x_2\leq\ldots\leq x_N\leq x_{N+1}=\infty$ to be the new random variable $\underline y$ produced by rounding each realization of $y\in[x_i,x_{i+1}]$ down to $x_i$ for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,N\}$. I'm interested in choosing the $x_i$s to maximize the mean of $\underline y$.

The question is, for any random variable $y$ as described above, is it possible to find a set of $N+1$ points whose corresponding $N$-rounding has mean at least $1-2/N$? Or, more generally, what's the largest mean that you can guarantee for any $y$, in terms of $N$?

Answer (score 0):

First, you must have meant $y \in [x_i, x_{i+1})$, or the whole
thing collapses to $a$.

Maybe I totally misunderstand this. But as I do understand it,
your conjecture is far from the mark.

I did a simulation with 100,000 samples of size n = 100 from
an exponential distribution with mean = 1 (also rate = 1).
I chose the lower boundaries $x_1, \dots, x_N$ to be integers
0 through 100. (It is possible, but extremely rare, for an
exponential random variable with mean 1 to exceed 100.)

The expected value of sample means of the down-rounded samples 
is much less than 0.6, which is very much below $1 - 2/100 = .98.$

In the simulation (using R) below, I used v for the original
un-rounded variables and y for the down-rounded ones.

```
 m = 10^5;  n = 100;  v = rexp(m*n, 1)
 y = v; y[v>=100] = 100;  y = floor(y)
 MAT = matrix(y, nrow=m)  # each sample of 100 a row
 y.bar = rowMeans(MAT)    # 100,000 sample means
 summary(y.bar)
        Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 ##   0.2100  0.5100  0.5800  0.5814  0.6400  1.0300
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! It seems like you got the gist of my question, fortunately. But my question is about the optimal choice of $x_i$s, and I suspect the solution $x_i=i-1$ is pretty far from optimal - the exponential distribution is pretty unlikely to have value greater than, say, 5. It follows the above rounding scheme is unnecessarily coarse in [0,5] and unnecessarily fine above that interval. Can the mean be pushed up to .98? I'm not convinced otherwise yet.

Comment: Both your question and its purpose are unclear. Before selecting the $x_i$, do I know the distribution? Do I get to see the data? In practice, it is best not to tamper unnecessarily with the data, and to round only at the end where extra places of accuracy would be hard to read or would give an undeserved illusion of precision.